# my python requests return 401 while postman returns 200

Tags: python, python-requests, postman

i make my requests class, the code is as below:

```
class RunMethod:

def post_main(self, url, data, header=None):
    res = None
    if header != None:
        res = requests.post(url=url, data=data, headers=header)
    else:
        res = requests.post(url=url, data=data)

    return res.json()

def get_main(self, url, data=None,header=None):
    res = None
    if header != None:
        res = requests.get(url=url,data=data,headers=header,verify=False)
    else:
        res = requests.get(url=url,data=data,verify=False)

    return res.json()

def run_main(self, method,url,data=None,headers=None):
    res = None
    if method == 'get':
        res = self.get_main(url, data, headers)
    else:
        res = self.post_main(url, data, headers)
```

and i capture an api from charles and test it in postman, it returns 200. i export python code from postman and it is like this:

```
import requests

url = "https://stargate.ar.elenet.me/minimart.service/intelligent/invoke"

querystring = {"traceId": "1000000294010",
           "shelfCode": "lu8ssMgCpgq00FDYdpX76Q..", "tracedAt": "1545641563164"}

payload = ""
headers = {
'X-STARGATE-ACCESS-TOKEN': "d7594351-0663-43a8-ad55-180c8b29db82",
'Cookie': "SID=NTVMAu8FKskyj06ln8J9uhS45fgcRNk1V3jQ; USERID=2228440841",
'Authorization': "ElemeAPI token",
'cache-control': "no-cache"
}

response = requests.request(
"GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

it works, and i changed my class, put the data like this:

```
url = "https://stargate.ar.elenet.me/minimart.service/intelligent/invoke?traceId=1000000294010&shelfCode=lu8ssMgCpgq00FDYdpX76Q..&tracedAt=1545641563164"
headers = {
    'X-STARGATE-ACCESS-TOKEN': "d7594351-0663-43a8-ad55-180c8b29db82",
    'Cookie': "SID=NTVMAu8FKskyj06ln8J9uhS45fgcRNk1V3jQ; USERID=2228440841",
    'Authorization': "ElemeAPI token",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
}

exam = RunMethod()
res = exam.run_main('get', url, headers)
```

i just put querystring into url, but it returns 401.
i don't know where it's wrong. could anybody help me? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code in get_main method as per below code.

`res = requests.get(url=url,params=data,headers=header,verify=False)`

Here we are calling instantiated RunMethod class and calling run_main method.

`exam = RunMethod()`

`res = exam.run_main('get', url, querystring, headers)`

Answer (score 0):

The `run_main` accepts 4 arguments, `exam.run_main('get', url, headers)` provides only 3 of them (`method='get', url=url, data=headers, headers=None`).

I would recommend to use named arguments when skipping some of the optional ones:

```
exam.run_main('get', url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: oh yes, you're right, i pass wrong parameters. thank you!